# Converting List of object to Guava Table data structure using lambda

Tags: java, java-8, guava

I have list of ImmutableTriple object where for first and middle there could collection of last values (first, middle and last are triple values).
Now in order to make it queryable, I need to convert it to Guava Table data structure. I am able to achieve this, with for loop as below but I am wondering if I can achieve this more functionally using lambda expression.
here is the piece code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //In real world, this list is coming from various transformation of lamda
    final List<ImmutableTriple<LocalDate, Integer, String>> list = ImmutableList.of(
            ImmutableTriple.of(LocalDate.now(), 1, "something"),
            ImmutableTriple.of(LocalDate.now(), 1, "anotherThing")
    );
    Table<LocalDate, Integer, List<String>> table = HashBasedTable.create();
    //is it possible to avoid this forEach and use side effect free lambda.
    list.forEach(s -> {
        final List<String> strings = table.get(s.left, s.middle);
        final List<String> slotList = strings == null ? new ArrayList<>() : strings;
        slotList.add(s.right);
        table.put(s.left, s.middle, slotList);
    });
    System.out.println(table);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `Tables` class which contains a `Collector` to get your desired result.

```
Table<LocalDate, Integer, ImmutableList<String>> collect = list.stream()
        .collect(Tables.toTable(
                it -> it.left,
                it -> it.middle,
                it -> ImmutableList.of(it.right),
                (l1, l2) -> ImmutableList.<String>builder()
                        .addAll(l1).addAll(l2).build(), 
                HashBasedTable::create));
```

---

If you really want a mutable `List` then you can use:

```
Table<LocalDate, Integer, List<String>> collect = list.stream()
        .collect(Tables.toTable(
                it -> it.left,
                it -> it.middle,
                it -> Lists.newArrayList(it.right),
                (l1, l2) -> {l1.addAll(l2); return l1;},
                HashBasedTable::create));
```

Comment: Thnx. From optimization perspective, every iteration creations one ImmutableList object. I have very big List and that could create so many objects. is it unavoidable?

Comment: @MohammadAdnan See my edit. This `Collector` is kind of limited and there will be some unnecessary object creations. This should not bother you because of GC.